# Proof about a function that uses rewrite: a "vertical bars in goals" question

Tags: agda

I have a function that uses `rewrite` to satisfy the Agda type checker. I thought that I had a reasonably good grasp of how to deal with the resulting "vertical bars" in proofs about such functions. And yet, I fail completely at dealing with these bars in my seemingly simple case.

Here are the imports and my function, `step`. The `rewrite`s make Agda see that `n` is equal to `n + 0` and that `suc (acc + n)` is equal to `acc + suc n`, respectively.

```
module Repro where

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P using (_≡_)

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.DivMod
open import Data.Nat.DivMod.Core
open import Data.Nat.Properties

open import Agda.Builtin.Nat using () renaming (mod-helper to modₕ)

step : (acc d n : ℕ) → modₕ acc (acc + n) d n ≤ acc + n
step zero d n rewrite P.sym (+-identityʳ n) = a[modₕ]n<n n (suc d) 0
step (suc acc) d n rewrite P.sym (+-suc acc n) = a[modₕ]n<n acc (suc d) (suc n)
```

Now for the proof, which pattern matches on `acc`, just like the function. Here's the `zero` case:

```
step-ok : ∀ (acc d n : ℕ) → step acc d n ≡ a[modₕ]n<n acc d n

step-ok zero d n with n        | P.sym (+-identityʳ n)
step-ok zero d n    | .(n + 0) | P.refl = ?
```

At this point, Agda tells me *I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor P.refl, because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification problems (inferred index ≟ expected index): w ≟ w + 0 [...]*

I am also stuck in the second case, the `suc acc` case, albeit in a different way:

```
step-ok (suc acc) d n with suc (acc + n)  | P.sym (+-suc acc n)
step-ok (suc acc) d n    | .(acc + suc n) | P.refl = ?
```

Here, Agda says *suc (acc + n) != w of type ℕ when checking that the type [...] of the generated with function is well-formed*

**Update after Sassa NF's response**

I followed Sassa NF's advice and reformulated my function with `P.subst` instead of `rewrite`. I.e., I changed my right-hand side from being about `n + 0` to being about `n`, instead of conversely changing the goal from being about `n` to being about `n + 0`:

```
step′ : (acc d n : ℕ) → modₕ acc (acc + n) d n ≤ acc + n
step′ zero d n = P.subst (λ # → modₕ 0 # d # ≤ #) (+-identityʳ n) (a[modₕ]n<n n (suc d) 0)
step′ (suc acc) d n = P.subst (λ # → modₕ (suc acc) # d n ≤ #) (+-suc acc n) (a[modₕ]n<n acc (suc d) (suc n))
```

During the proof, the `P.subst` in the function definition needs to be eliminated, which can be done with a `with` construct:

```
step-ok′ : ∀ (acc d n : ℕ) → step′ acc d n ≡ a[modₕ]n<n acc d n

step-ok′ zero d n with n + 0 | +-identityʳ n
...                  | .n    | P.refl = P.refl

step-ok′ (suc acc) d n with acc + suc n      | +-suc acc n
...                       | .(suc (acc + n)) | P.refl = P.refl
```

So, yay! I just finished my very first Agda proof involving a `with`.

**Some progress on the original problem**

My guess would be that my first issue is a unification issue during dependent pattern matching: there isn't any substitution that makes `n` identical to `n + 0`. More generally, in situations where one thing is a strict subterm of the other thing, I suppose that we may run into unification trouble. So, maybe using `with` to match `n` with `n + 0` was asking for problems.

My second issue seems to be what the Agda language reference calls an *ill-typed `with`-abstraction*. According to the reference, this "happens when you abstract over a term that appears in the type of a subterm of the goal or argument types." The culprit seems to be the type of the goal's subterm `a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n`, which is `modₕ [...] ≤ (suc acc) + n`, which contains the subterm I abstract over, `(suc acc) + n`.

It looks like this is usually resolved by additionally abstracting over the part of the goal that has the offending type. And, indeed, the following makes the error message go away:

```
step-ok (suc acc) d n with suc (acc + n)  | P.sym (+-suc acc n) | a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n
...                      | .(acc + suc n) | P.refl              | rhs                      = {!!}
```

So far so good. Let's now introduce `P.inspect` to capture the `rhs` substitution:

```
step-ok (suc acc) d n with suc (acc + n)  | P.sym (+-suc acc n) | a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n | P.inspect (a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d) n
...                      | .(acc + suc n) | P.refl              | rhs                      | P.[ rhs-eq ]                         = {!!}
```

Unfortunately, this leads to something like the original error: *w != suc (acc + n) of type ℕ when checking that the type [...] of the generated with function is well-formed*

**One day later**

Of course I'd run into the same ill-typed with-abstraction again! After all, the whole point of `P.inspect` is to *preserve* `a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n`, so that it can construct the term `a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n ≡ rhs`. However, preserved `a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n` of course still has its preserved original type, `modₕ [...] ≤ (suc acc) + n`, whereas `rhs` has the modified type `modₕ [...] ≤ acc + suc n`. That's what's causing trouble now.

I guess one solution would be to use `P.subst` to change the type of the term we inspect. And, indeed, the following works, even though it is hilariously convoluted:

```
step-ok (suc acc) d n with suc (acc + n)  | P.sym (+-suc acc n) | a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n | P.inspect (λ n → P.subst (λ # → modₕ (suc acc) # d n ≤ #) (P.sym (+-suc acc n)) (a[modₕ]n<n (suc acc) d n)) n
...                      | .(acc + suc n) | P.refl              | rhs                      | P.[ rhs-eq ]                                                                                                  rewrite +-suc acc n = rhs-eq
```

So, yay again! I managed to fix my original second issue - basically by using `P.subst` in the proof instead of in the function definition. It seems, though, that using `P.subst` in the function definition as per Sassa NF's guidance is preferable, as it leads to much more concise code.

The unification issue is still a little mysterious to me, but on the positive side, I unexpectedly learned about the benefits of irrelevance on top of everything.

I'm accepting Sassa NF's response, as it put me on the right track towards a solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but may help with your original problem: `<=` should be a proposition, meaning for all `n, m` and `p q : n <= m`, `p = q`. `step-ok` then follows directly.

Comment: Ooooh... clever! I found out about proof-irrelevance a few days ago, but I completely missed just how useful it is. So, thank you very much for sharing this. I'm definitely going to revisit irrelevance now, because suddenly I see this pattern all over my proofs, where it would help to use the fact that a _p_ at hand is not just *a* proof, but *the* proof of something. The standard library doesn't put `<=` into `Prop`, though, does it? It seems to be in `Set`. So, Agda wouldn't know that `<=` is a proposition, no? Again, thanks for sharing this. I am intrigued to look into this more.

Comment: The word "proposition" is a bit overloaded these days. What I call a proposition is any type `P` such that `∀ (p q : P), p ≡ q`. If `P : Prop`, this is true definitionally. But for some `P : Set`, you can still prove this as a lemma. The standard library already has it: `Data.Nat.Properties.≤-irrelevant`.

Comment: Aaaaaah! I see! How nice! I just tried it out in a proof by induction and used it to rewrite a side condition in the inductive step to make it match the induction hypothesis. Works like a charm! Quite the gem! Thanks again for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `P.refl` indicates some misunderstanding about the role of `_≡_`.

There is no magic in that type. It is just a dependent type with a single constructor. Proving that some `x ≡ y` resolves to `P.refl` does not tell Agda anything new about `x` and `y`: it only tells Agda that you managed to produce a witness of the type `_≡_`. This is the reason it cannot tell `n` and `.(n + 0)` are the same thing, or that `suc (acc + n)` is the same as `.(acc + suc n)`. So both of the errors you see are really the same.

Now, what `rewrite` is for.

You cannot define `C x ≡ C y` for dependent type `C _`. `C x` and `C y` are different types. Equality is defined only for elements of the same type, so there is no way to even express the idea that an element of type `C x` is comparable to an element of type `C y`.

There is, however, an axiom of induction, which allows to produce elements of type `C y`, if you have an element of type `C x` and an element of type `x ≡ y`. Note there is no magic in the type `_≡_` - that is, you can define your own type, and construct such a function, and Agda will be satisfied:

```
induction : {A : Set} {C : (x y : A) -> (x ≡ y) -> Set} (x y : A) (p : x ≡ y) ((x : A) -> C x x refl) -> C x y p
induction x .x refl f = f x
```

Or a simplified version that follows from the induction axiom:

```
transport : {A : Set} {C : A -> Set} (x y : A) (x ≡ y) (C x) -> C y
transport x .x refl cx = cx
```

What this means in practice, is that you get a proof for something - for example, `A x ≡ A x`, but then transport this proof along the equality `x ≡ y` to get a proof `A x ≡ A y`. This usually requires specifying the type explicitly, in this case `{C = y -> A x ≡ A y}`, and provide the `x`, the `y` and the `C x`. As such, it is a very cumbersome procedure, although the learners will benefit from doing these steps.

`rewrite` then is a syntactic mechanism that rewrites the types of the terms known before the rewrite, so that such `transport` is not needed after that. Because it is syntactic, it does interpret the type `_≡_` in a special way (so if you define your own type, you need to tell Agda you are using a different type as equality). Rewriting types is not "telling" Agda that some types are equal. It just literally replaces occurrences of `x` in type signatures with `y`, so now you only need to construct things with `y` and `refl`.

Having said all that, you can see why it works for `step`. There `rewrite P.sym ...` literally replaced all occurrences of `n` with `n + 0`, including the return type of the function, so now it is `modₕ acc (acc + (n + 0)) d (n + 0) ≤ acc + (n + 0)`. Then constructing a value of that type just works.

Then `step-ok` didn't work, because you only pattern-matched values. There is nothing to tell that `n` and `(n + 0)` are the same thing. But `rewrite` will. Or you could use a function like this `transport`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive explanation and for your time. It seems, then, that I could use Agda's `P.subst` (your `transport`) to change the type of `a[modₕ]n<n` instead of using `rewrite` to change the type of the goal. Awesome! That gives me a way out of this. I'll try that for my edification. However, what you say about `rewrite` seems to contradict what I read in the language reference, i.e., that `rewrite` is just syntactic sugar for exactly the `with` construct that I'm using. Would it be possible to elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Maybe it makes sense for me to also elaborate a little more on how I thought things work, so that it becomes more obvious where my misconception is: While the equality type isn't special, it does take two type parameters of identical type. Pattern matching with any type like this (i.e., not just the equality type) introduces the constraint to the pattern matching context that the two types must be equal, e.g., that `n` is identical to `n + 0`. Thus, all `n`s in the context can be replaced by `n + 0`s. That's how I thought `rewrite` works, i.e., via unification instead of textual rewriting.

Comment: I admit I got out of touch with `with`. `rewrite` is declared to be implemented as `with`. But even a simple thing like `eq-z n with sym (+-identity n); ... | refl = refl` doesn't work, whereas `eq-z n rewrite sym (+-identity n) = refl` does. So it's not quite a like-for-like...

Comment: How weird. Oh, well. In any case, thank you very much for explaining the equality type and `P.subst` in great detail! This significantly improved my understanding of what's going on. Great!